# Groovy override constructor named parameters

Tags: groovy

Giving class

```
class A {
    def String name = ''
    def String lower = ''
}
```

Constructor with named parameters can be used

```
new A(name: 'Alice', lower: 'alice')
```

I don't want to specify lower parameter as it is always equals to name.toLowerCase()

How to implement this constructor? 
So after calling:

```
def a = new A(name: 'Alice')
println "${a.lower}"
```

alice will be printed

Comment: could you use just a getter? `String getLower() { name.toLowerCase() }`?

Comment: @cfrick Of course I can. It is just interesting to me is it available via modifying constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not sure, what you are really after here.  if you really need some magic only for the ctor, let us know.  but the most common ways to solve this, would either be:

1. calculate the `lower`, when it's needed

   ```
   String getLower() { name.toLowerCase() }
   ```
2. override the setter of `name`

   ```
   class A {
       String name = ''
       private String lower = ''

       void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name
           this.lower = name?.toLowerCase()
       }

       String getLower() { lower }

   }

   def a = new A(name: 'Charlie')
   assert a.lower == 'charlie'
   ```